# mySQL LIKE operator that does not equal

Tags: mysql, sql-like

How can i write a mySQL query where i am looking for something using the LIKE operator and NOT equaling what is LIKE?

```
select * from ets_fi where name like '%barcode&' <> '%barcode%';
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NOT LIKE

```
select * from ets_fi where name NOT LIKE '%barcode%';
```

OR, if I misunderstood your intention, you may want:

```
select * from ets_fi where name LIKE '%barcode%' AND name != 'barcode';
```